The universal covering of $B \simeq \mathbb{D} / \Gamma$ where $\Gamma \subset {\rm PSL}\, (2,\mathbb{C})$ is a Fuchsian group?
Let $B$ be a simply connected Riemann surface such that $B \simeq \mathbb{D} / \Gamma$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc and $\Gamma \subset {\rm PSL}\, (2,\mathbb{C})$ is a Fuchsian group.
Is it possible to say the universal covering of $B$ is the hyperbolic disc $\mathbb{D}$? and Why?

Do you mean $\Gamma \subset PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$?
Under your conditions, since $B$ is simply connected this means that $\Gamma=\pi_1(B)$ is trivial...
More generally, whenever a group $\Gamma$ acts properly discontinuously on a simply connected space $X$ (such as a Fuschian group on the hyperbolic plane) then $X$ is the universal cover of $X/\Gamma$.

Your final sentence is not accurate. Proper discontinuity is not sufficient, one also needs the action to be free. Fuchsian groups are not, in general, required to act freely (unlike deck groups of universal covering spaces). For example if $\Gamma$ is a von Dyck group then it does not act freely, the orbit map projection from $X =$ (the hyperbolic plane) to $X/\Gamma$ is not a covering map, and $X/\Gamma$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$.
